# Sidekiq concurrency issues with HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have 3 sidekiq processes that each has 10 threads working.
The problem is that each task does HTTP request (using faraday or HTTParty) but the concurrency seems to be blocked.
That is, I see in `netstat -nalp` that there are only 3 connections at a time to that specific port (even though there are 30 workers running at the same time).
I tried doing `Thread.ne`w with the same logic OUTSIDE of the sidekiq and its extremely fast. I feel as if sidekiq is using some pool between the threads. Could it be? I tried both HTTParty and Faraday.

I noticed that for every process (not thread) there is only active connection at a time!
This is the problem, however how can this be fixed?

```
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60139      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60044      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60000      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60055      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60149      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    ESTABLISHED 9702/sidekiq 4.2.10
tcp        1      0 172.31.55.12:60145      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    CLOSE_WAIT  27895/sidekiq 4.2.1
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60065      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60021      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60033      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60148      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    ESTABLISHED 10234/sidekiq 4.2.1
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:59976      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60099      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60066      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.55.12:60039      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:22225    TIME_WAIT   -
```

My code:

```
def check_heartbeat(asset)
  res = Proxy.new("https://www.example.com/#{asset.external_code}/", 30).head

  archived = true if res.status == 404 && !asset.external_code.nil?
  ...

end

def perform(asset_id, asset_type)
  check_heartbeat(asset)
end

class Proxy

    NUM_OF_RETRIES = 3
    TIMEOUT = 10

    def initialize(url, timeout = TIMEOUT, retries = NUM_OF_RETRIES)
      @url = url
      @timeout = timeout
      @retries = retries
      @session_id = rand(100000).to_s
    end

    def head
      retries = 0
      begin
        conn = Faraday.new(@url, ssl: {verify: false}) do |conn|
          conn.request  :url_encoded
          conn.response :logger
          conn.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
          conn.use  Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
          conn.proxy("http://#{ENV['PROXY_USER'].present? ? ENV['PROXY_USER'].gsub('xxx', @session_id) : nil}:#{ENV['PROXY_PASSWORD']}@#{ENV['PROXY_HOST']}:#{ENV['PROXY_PORT']}")
        end

        conn.head

      rescue Exception => ex
        if retries < @retries          
          retries += 1
          retry
        end

        raise Exception.new("Proxy failed")
      end
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the Net::HTTP `open_timeout`? (ref: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#frozen-processes) Having a look at the worker code would be beneficial.

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge - This is irrelevant. I tested with 1000 threads doing the same logic and it opens hundreds of sockets and finishes pretty quickly. its something with the way sidekiq works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like HTTParty or Faraday is limiting the number of open connections per hostname.  Might want to check into that.

Comment: Correct, they are running in each process so the limiter would be per-process.

Comment: You aren't showing us any code so we have no way to understand if your usage is right or wrong.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks. I updated the code. Be aware the ... at the end of the function is just calculations so there is no bottleneck there, btw - I tested the same logic with 1000 threads in a rails console and its working perfectly. Its something with the sidekiq way of work